# Laravel Livewire - how to get @push to work?

Tags: php, laravel, push, laravel-livewire

Not sure what I'm missing here, but nothing I do seems to allow `@push('styles')` or `@push ('scripts')` to work.

`layout/app.blade.php` includes:

```
...

 @livewireStyles

...

 @livewireScripts

...
```

`livewire/tagify.blade.php`

```
@push('styles')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify@3.11.1/dist/tagify.min.css">


@endpush

@push('scripts')
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify@3.11.1/dist/tagify.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var input = document.getElementById('tagify')
    var tagify = new Tagify(input, {
      whitelist : [
        @foreach($tags as $tag)
          '{{ $tag }}'@if(! $loop->last), @endif
        @endforeach
      ]
    })
    input.addEventListener('change', onChange)

    function onChange(e){
      @this.call('changeTags', e.target.value)
    }

  })
  </script>

@endpush
```

The rest of the component is included fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nevermind,

turns out `layout/app.blade.php` seems to also need

```
@stack('scripts')
```

and

```
@stack('styles')
```

for `@push` to work.

Comment: This is still valid for Livewire 3 as well

Answer (score 4):

Livewire component can only push to any layout stack only in page load, after any subsequent component render push to stack will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if there is a style stack. Because the stack name can also be
`@stack('custome-name')` .
Whatever you want.

It would be important to mention that you set the stack directive in the parent. And in the child blade file you use the @push directive with the corresponding name. In our example `@push('custom-name').`

The push directive is best set at the top of the child. Because it might cause problems with Laravel's view compnent.
(`<x-app>...</x-app>`)
can occur.

Comment: "The push directive is best set at the top of the child. Because it might cause problems with Laravel's view compnent. (<x-app>...</x-app>) can occur." this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Thrussell poited out please esure you add

```php
@stack('styles')
@stack('scripts')
```

in your parent blade file. I.e the same way you do `@yield('content')` to render component data to parent layout. check here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/1.x/inline-scripts for more information