Unable to @push inline styles in Livewire Laravel app
I am new to Laravel/Alpine/Tailwind. Based on tutorials I wanted to have a simple modal come up.
My model-component.blade.php

<div>
    <!-- Button to open the modal -->
    <button wire:click="openModal" class="button">Open Confirm Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    @if($isOpen)
        <div class="modal" style="display:flex">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p>Are you sure you want to proceed?</p>
                <!-- Confirmation buttons -->
                <div class="mt-4 flex justify-center space-x-4">
                    <button class="button bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700" wire:click="closeModal">Yes</button>
                    <button class="button bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700" wire:click="closeModal">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>

@push('styles12')
<style>
    /* Basic styling for modal background */
    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* semi-transparent background */
        display: none;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    /* Modal content styling */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 2rem;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
    }

    /* Button styles */
    .button {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        background-color: #3490dc;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button:hover {
        background-color: #2779bd;
    }

    .modal button {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
</style>
@endpush

My Modalcomponent.php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ModalComponent extends Component
{
    public $isOpen = false;

    public function openModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.modal-component');
    }
}

in my app.blade.php I do:
  <livewire:modal-component />

The CSS does not get rendered. When I place the CSS in app.css everything is fine.
What am I missing?

You may find the answer to this question helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408610/laravel-livewire-how-to-get-push-to-work
